# <ion-tabs> não é renderizado

Tags: ionic

Tenho uma page chamada footer-tabs que deveria renderizar a tabs do ionic, mas ela não está sendo mostrada.

Meu footer-tab template:

```
<ion-tabs>
    <ion-tab tabIcon="list" tabTitle="Games"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-footeer-tab',
  templateUrl: 'footeer-tab.html',
})
export class FooteerTabPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }


}
```

No meu componente home, tento chamar através do seletor, mas nada é renderizado:

```
  <page-footeer-tab></page-footeer-tab>
```

Estou esquecendo de algo em especial?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode chamar a página no app.component.ts usando `this.nav.setRoot("FooteerTabPage");`.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que fazendo essas modificações seu código ja funcione, você precisa especificar qual page você quer abrir com a tab.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-footeer-tab',
  templateUrl: 'footeer-tab.html',
})
export class FooteerTabPage {
  public tab1Root = "SUAPAGEAQUI";
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams)   {
  
  }
}
```

```html
<ion-tabs>
    <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabIcon="list" tabTitle="Games"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```